# Add class when window resized and use added class to trigger accordion content - not working

Tags: jquery, addclass, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using accordion on mobile size of page layout. I have jQuery which adds class (.mobile) to h3 tag. Idea is that .mobile class is used to trigger accordion content. But I cant get it work. When I change .mobile to h3 in accordion jQuery it works, but with added .mobile class accordion does not work. Why?

Here is [working JSFIDDLE with h3 in accordion trigger](http://jsfiddle.net/9jy5pw9m/18/) example. When changing Result window Accordion is working and you can open content by clicking title.

Here is one with [added mobile class to to trigger - not working JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9jy5pw9m/17/). I have added line `jQuery( "h3" ).addClass( "mobile" );`. So it adds mobile class to h3. Why accordion is not working with this added .mobile class?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *".mobile class is used to trigger accordion content"*? i opened your fiddle in fullscreen you nothing works at all... what is supposed to happen in that fiddle?

Comment: Resize Result window in JSFIDDLE to smaller. Then it adds .mobile class to h3 tag. Then you should be able to click Content1, Content2 and Content3 to open them - as accordion. But with .mobile class it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `jQuery('mobile')` should be `jQuery('.mobile')` in different places.
- Your script is set to be executed`onLoad`, So the IIFE which triggers the `resize`, which in turn adds the `.mobile` class will be executed after the `ready()` handler. Changing the script execution to `No wrap` will fix this

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9jy5pw9m/19/)

*P.S: I wonder why you have two resize handlers, a document ready, an `IIFE` and some loose code outside both... All you probably need is just the document ready and a resize handler*

Comment: Okey, that makes .mobile class to work in accordion. But seems that it needs page reload to accordion work. So when user has full page view he can click title and make accordion work - this is not wanted. Accordion should only work in under 500px window.

Comment: @ace Your question was *"but with added .mobile class accordion does not work. Why?"* that has been answered. If you have a new blocker based on the solution, try to fix it, if you're unable to - then post a different question. this is a `Q&A` site, not were somebody follows you through till all your *requirements* are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code in the .ready function like this:

```
jQuery('.page-title').click(function() {           //.page-title class is added
        if(jQuery(this).data("slided") === true) {
            jQuery(this).next().slideUp('normal');
            jQuery(this).data("slided", false);
        } else {
            jQuery('.page-title').data('slided',false);    //.page-title class is added
            jQuery('.sec').slideUp('normal');   
            jQuery(this).next().slideDown('normal');
            jQuery(this).data("slided", true);
        }
    });
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/9jy5pw9m/20/).